# What is non key attribute in sql server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know what do we mean by a non key attribute in sql server. This think is related to table i am confused. Does it mean the column other then primary key

Comment: first hit in a quick search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Answer (score 5):

A non key attribute in sql server is a columns which can not be used to identify a record uniquely for example name or age  columns in customer table.